# Check existence of a list of issues in Jira

Tags: java, rest, jira

I have a list of (say) 100 potential Jira issue keys (like "SPU-123") and want to check if they really exist in our Jira.

Making 100 separate REST calls is quite slow. Any idea to do this quicker?

Comment: Using thread pool, each thread calling the REST api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[POST request](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.11.2/?_ga=2.184000614.1502779126.1534073750-443767027.1533383566#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest) with a following JQL:

```
{
  "startIndex": 0,
  "jql": "key in (ABC-1,ABC-2,ABC-3)",
  "layoutKey": "list-view"
}
```

will result in HTTP400 error in case of missing issue with detailed message:

```
{
  "errorMessages": [
    "An issue with key 'ABC-1' does not exist for field 'id'.",
    "An issue with key 'ABC-3' does not exist for field 'id'."
  ],
  "errors": {}
}
```